# MS SQL case then statement with more than one column

Tags: sql-server

I want to return multiple column in the case when .... then  col1 ,col2 , col3
or use * .

my query  is :

```
 select a.param1, case
              when b.param1 is not null then  b.loc_ID , 'july'
              when c.param1 is not null then c.loc_ID , 'may'
              else ''
              end
  from [dbo].[table1] a
  left join [dbo].[USERS_7_30] b
  on a.param1 = b.pram1
  left join [dbo].[USERS_6_30] c
  on a.param1 = c.pram1
```

I get this response:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 147
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: Based on your table names, I think you might want to come up with a strategy for merging those `USER_<month>_<day>` tables, then working with the merged data set so that you aren't fighting this fight every month.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use separate case when statement

```
select a.param1, 
              case
              when b.param1 is not null then b.loc_ID 
              when c.param1 is not null then c.loc_ID 
              else ''
              end,
              case
              when b.param1 is not null then 'july'
              when c.param1 is not null then 'may'
              else ''
              end
  from [dbo].[table1] a
  left join [dbo].[USERS_7_30] b
  on a.param1 = b.pram1
  left join [dbo].[USERS_6_30] c
  on a.param1 = c.pram1
```

Comment: thank you, so incase I want more fields I have to repeat again. Is there another method that I can use ? like if then , can it be better in my case ?

Comment: `IF THEN` is for flow control, not for query. I am afraid there isn't any other way that i can think off

Answer (score 1):

That's not how a `CASE` **expression** works. A `CASE` expression can only return  single scalar value. You'll have to use multiple expressions:

```
SELECT a.param1,
       CASE WHEN b.param1 IS NOT NULL THEN b.loc_ID WHEN c.param1 IS NOT NULL THEN c.loc_ID ELSE '' END AS loc_id,
       CASE WHEN b.param1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'July' WHEN c.param1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'May' ELSE '' END AS loc_id
FROM [dbo].[table1] a
     LEFT JOIN [dbo].[USERS_7_30] b ON a.param1 = b.pram1
     LEFT JOIN [dbo].[USERS_6_30] c ON a.param1 = c.pram1;
```

Your `ELSE` only had 1 return value, so I *assumed* `''` should be returned for both columns.